# QQuickView window freezes upon mouse resize

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have problem resizing the window using this example. It works, but unpredictable when it becomes unresponsive. Window minimization and maximization works every time, but resizing with the mouse causes weird, frozen behavior. Happens on Windows 10 using Qt 5.12.0. What I do wrong here?
Thanks!

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And this is the main QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out the solution:

`anchors.fill: parent` should not be used in the root element, but instead we have to tell to the view in C++ the following:

```
view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
```

Comment: I would advice you to use `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` as a root item since this is more configurable and native way.

Comment: In our application we have an OpenGL window that shows a 3D scene and the QML Item/Rectangle container overlays this window which holds the UI elements. Using a window in QML would result an additional unwanted windows instead of an overlay. Important that we need to do stuff with this window in C++ so it is essential that we create the view/window there.